# BeautifulSoup and Chrome driver are unable to get div tag by class name from Kayak flight search

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to use classname to identify valid search result list then iterate to scrap price. However, the code is still unable to identify the class. I know it used javascript, but I thought selenium can identify the tag after rendering. Which part I am wrong? Appreciate

[image]

```
import time
import subprocess
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
#from playsound import playsound
import datetime
import threading
service = Service(executable_path='xxx')


option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_argument("--headless=new")
option.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
option.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
option.add_argument('disable-notifications')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service,options=option)

def search(dep,arr,date):
    print(f'''Input: Date:{date},Departure: {dep} - Arrival: {arr}''')
    temp_url = 'https://www.kayak.com/flights/'

    base_url = temp_url + dep+'-'+arr+'/'+str(date)+'?sort=price_a&fs=stops=0'

    
    df_record = pd.DataFrame(columns=['deptime','arrtime','dep','arr',
                                     'airline' ,'flightNum','price','ling'])  
    print("before webdriver.ChromeOptions()")
   
    my_url = base_url
    driver.get(my_url)
    print(my_url)
    time.sleep(3) # set the time to wait till web fully loaded
    
    # wait for the close button to be visible and click it
    try:
        close_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@class="nrc6"]')
        close_button.click()
    except:
        print("close is not found.")

    
    elem = driver.find_element("xpath","//*")
    
    source_code = elem.get_attribute("outerHTML")
    #print(source_code)
    bs = BeautifulSoup(source_code, 'html.parser')
    #print(bs)
    #expand 
    drawing_url = bs.find_all('button', class_='nrc6')
    print(len(drawing_url)) # this shouldn't be zero
    if len(drawing_url)==0: return
    else: print(base_url)
```

Comment: I saw your screenshot. Is there an IFrame element in the page you are checking?
Just checked the page, IFrames are used on other elements, what error did you get and which line?

Comment: @PQCo, no errors, just this line "drawing_url = bs.find_all('button', class_='nrc6')" is zero result, meaning not found the classname.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I were able to understand your concern.
But basically, you want to get the list of prices from the website.
As per checking, the prices are using the same class which is "f8F1-price-text".

```
    driver.get("https://www.kayak.com/flights/SFO-TYO/2024-03-21/2024-03-28?sort=bestflight_a");
    
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    By tempElement = By.xpath("//div[@class='nrc6']");
    List <WebElement> elmTicketDetails = driver.findElements(tempElement);
    System.out.println("====================================================================================================================");
    for (int cnt = 1; cnt <= elmTicketDetails.size(); cnt++) {
        By byFromDetail = By.xpath("//div[@class='nrc6'][" + cnt + "]//li[@class='hJSA-item'][1]");
        By byToDetail = By.xpath("//div[@class='nrc6'][" + cnt + "]//li[@class='hJSA-item'][2]");
        By byPrice = By.xpath("//div[@class='nrc6'][" + cnt + "]//div[@class='f8F1-price-text']");
        WebElement elmFromDetail = driver.findElement(byFromDetail);
        WebElement elmToDetail = driver.findElement(byToDetail);
        WebElement elmPrice = driver.findElement(byPrice);
        System.out.println("Details for Ticket # " + cnt);
        System.out.println("Flight From: " + elmFromDetail.getText());
        System.out.println("Flight To: " + elmToDetail.getText());
        System.out.println("Price: " + elmPrice.getText());
        System.out.println("====================================================================================================================");
    }
```

The response is:

```
====================================================================================================================
Details for Ticket # 1
Flight From: 12:20 pm – 7:20 pm
+2
EVA Air
1 stop
TPE
39h 00m
SFO
-
NRT
Flight To: 1:00 pm – 6:40 am
+1
EVA Air
1 stop
TPE
33h 40m
NRT
-
SFO
Price: $1,207
====================================================================================================================
Details for Ticket # 2
Flight From: 11:50 am – 3:10 pm
...
```

This is written in Java, but the logic should be the same.

Update: Updated the code for a sample, I printed it as a whole, but you can declare multiple locators to point to the specific details.

e.g.
If you want to get the time only:
[image]

Comment: thanks. also airport name, duration,and flight number. I saw in final result, it is organized listing with different resultid in DIV and same class name='nrc6'. I thought if I can use class name to capture them and save to a list, then I can use a loop to iterate them. do not know why BS can not get find that class name, maybe something wrong in my code?

Comment: thx alot. mine is beautifulsoap issue not chrome driver issue, it doesn't capture the div

Comment: do you have idea about the Chromedriver headless not working issue?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78093600/option-add-argument-headless-doesnt-work-for-chrome-122-when-scrap-kayak? thx